# switching fragment by onclicklistener in activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity, fragment, switching

I have application with fragments, and I want to switch between them by a button-operated activity. Here is my try. How can I do it?

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    public static Context appContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        MeinFragment A_fragment = new MeinFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, A_fragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        ImageButton BTN1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.leftButton);
        BTN1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SearchFragment A_fragment = new SearchFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, A_fragment);

            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

My second try, but application crashed.

public class StartActivity extends Activity {
    public static Context appContext;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


    MeinFragment A_fragment = new MeinFragment();


    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, A_fragment);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();


  //Fragments changing
    ImageButton BTN1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.leftButton);
   BTN1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {



          FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


          SearchFragment B_fragment = new SearchFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, B_fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

       }
       });

}
```

}

And logcat:

01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.arvidg.exampleactionbartabs/de.arvidg.exampleactionbartabs.StartActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at de.arvidg.exampleactionbartabs.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:52)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-27 17:37:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(3339):     ... 11 more

Answer (score 0):

```
fragmentTransaction
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(android.R.id.content, A_fragment)
    .commit();
```

you need to begin transaction and commit to complete operation.

Comment: check the line number 52, that's the cause of problem

Comment: On line 52 is comment:"//Fragments changing"

Answer (score 0):

Refering to javadoc for FragmentTransaction.beginTransaction():

Note: A fragment transaction can only be created/committed prior to an activity saving its state. If you try to commit a transaction after Activity.onSaveInstanceState() (and **prior to a following Activity.onStart or Activity.onResume()**, you will get an error. This is because the framework takes care of saving your current fragments in the state, and if changes are made after the state is saved then they will be lost.

Comment: It isn't it in onSaveInstanceState() ?

Comment: Code is calling methods replace() and commit() in onCreate():